# Dispatching action in thunk results in error: can't get state of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Here is the action itself:

```
import actionFromAnotherReducer from '../subfolder/reducer'

export const asyncAction = createAsyncThunk(
  'reducerName/actionName',
  async(
    data,
    { dispatch, getState }
  ) => {
    return somePromise.then(response => {
      dispatch(actionFromAnotherReducer(response))
    })
  }
)
```

And here is where I get this error
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')`: `The above error occurred in the <Provider> component`. The thing is when I remove the dispatch(action), everything works, and also if I dispatch an action from the same folder reducer, it works as well. How to fix it?

Comment: Which what exact code are you dispatching this thunk?

Comment: @phry, I dispatch another action created with createAsyncThunk

Comment: I already asked very explicitly: With what exact code? Your thunk is totally fine, the chance that you are dispatching it wrong is very high.

Comment: @phry, `dispatch(asyncAction({ title: 'test title' }))`

Comment: So that's not your problem. Then I would assume you have created some kind of circular import. Do you create your store in a separate file or in the same file as in the `Provider`? Can you move it into it's own file? Does your thunk file import something from that same file where your store is currently in or from a file that imports from there?